# How to enter one dimensional array filled with unknown values of variable

Tags: java

I'm a Java beginner and I don't understand how to make it. When I write in my code something like in the example, my IDE underlines it and says it's wrong when I only started writing my code. Can anybody help me guys?

Example:

```
public class ArrayUtils {
    public static int[] lookFor(int[] array) {
      int[] array = {};

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does it underline and what error message does it display?

Comment: IDE underlines the array word and displays "Variable "array" is already defined in the scope".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable named `array` is already passed in as a parameter. Which means that you cannot create a new `int[]` named `array` inside the java method. Try naming it something else.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax with `{}` means initialization of your array like `int[] array = {1,2,3}`.
But you can't initialize the variable with the same name as parameter's name.

You can assign a new array to the variable:

```
public static int[] lookFor(int[] array) {
    array = new int[6];  // assign to variable new array with length 6
    array = new int[]{1,3,5};    // assign to variable new array with initialized values

}
```

Note: in first case all 6 values will be zero

**Update**: as it was mentioned by @ernest_k reassigning method parameters is a bad practice. To avoid it method parameter usually marked as final `int[] lookFor(final int[] array)`